# Can I track email campaign with google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

Can I track the location of the user by using google analytics in my email campaign ?

I've read few articles on this and confused. Few say It's not possible, few others say it is violating GA terms&conditions.
Some people say It is possible with Universal Analytics. (But no where I've seen an example/procedure).

Is it really possible to track the location ??
If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics is a brilliant tool to describe the details of your web application access from any part of the world in the dashboard. Here you can track the number of users access from location. I don't think if google analytics implemented that approach to send notification on each access to registered email address.